# Link the movement of a div to the movement of another div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an alcohol simulator, so when I press a button, you see an alcohol bottle being drained, but at the same time I should see the stomach filling. I have a code already for 'drinking', but I want to fix that if the water of the bottle moves 2 steps, that the water of the stomach only moves one step. I'll put just the js here, if you want the html as well, let me know.

```
var top_max = 475,
top_min = 400,
left_max = 200;

function move_img(str) {
    var step = 1; // change this to different step value
    var el = document.getElementById('i1');
    var el2 = document.getElementById('i2');

if (str == 'up' || str == 'down') {
    var top = el.offsetTop;
    var height = el.offsetHeight;
    console.log(height);
    if (str == 'up') {
        top -= step;
        height += step;
    } else {
        top += step;
        height -=step;
    }
    if (top_max >= top && top >= 110) {
        document.getElementById('i1').style.top = top + "px";
        document.getElementById('i1').style.height = height;
    } else {
        clearInterval(myVar)
    }
} else if (str == 'left' || str == 'right') {
    var left = el.offsetLeft;
    if (str == 'left') {
        left += step;
    } else {
        left -= step;
    }
    if (top_left < left && left >= 0) {
        document.getElementById('i1').style.left = top + "px";
    } else {
        clearInterval(myVar)
    }
}



}


function auto(str) {
    myVar = setInterval(function () {
        move_img(str);
    }, 90);
}

function nana() {}

var myVar;

function handler() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
    auto(this.id);
}



function auto(str) {

 myVar = setInterval(function(){ move_img(str); }, 2)  ;



}


function stop(){

setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( myVar ); }, 1);


}
```

Comment: make a complete [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) out of it and let us see it in action

Comment: for some kind of reason they neve rwork for me